# Calculate log for a column with zeros in vaex

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, vaex

I am looking to calculate the log of one of my columns in Vaex. The problem is that some of the rows in my column have the value of 0. The following works if the column doesn't contain zero:

```
df['log_axis'] = np.log(df['original_axis'])
```

I have tried a number of approaches to  get this to work with zero as values.
I tried using np.where to default those zeros to a min value (anything below .0001 gets mapped to -4):

```
df['log_axis'] = np.where(df['original_axis'] > 0.0001  , np.log(df['original_axis']), -4)
```

From this I get the error `TypeError: len() of unsized object`

I tried using a regular if statement:

```
df['log_axis'] = np.log(df['original_axis']) if df['original_axis'] > 0.0001  else -4
```

This gives me the error `ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity`

I tried using the where statement in the np.log function:

```
df['log_axis'] = np.log(df['original_axis'], where=df['original_axis'] > 0.0001)
```

I get the also get following error from this: `ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity`

None of these has worked. How can I calculate the log of a column with zeros? Am I on the right track to default the lowest value? If so how do I properly calculate this value in a virtual column?

Comment: This is general maths, where log is valid on positive non-zero numbers. 
I guess you can "impute" the zeros, drop those rows, or specify a way to handle them. 
you can also use `np.log1p` like was already suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This is only an indirect answer and might not be useful in some contexts, but if your downstream analysis is robust to `log(1+x)` transformation, then using [`np.log1p`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.log1p.html) might help:

```py
df['log_axis'] = np.log1p(df['original_axis'])
```